# If $M$ is complete is the closed ball compact?

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p,q \in M$. Let $\Omega=\Omega(M;p,q)$ be the set of piecewise $C^\infty$ paths from $p$ to $q$. Let $\rho$ denote the topological metric on $M$ coming from its Riemann metric. Let $S$ denote the ball $\{x \in M : \rho(x,p) \le \sqrt{c}\}$ with $c >0$. Why if $M$ is complete is $S$ compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is complete, the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Riemannian_geometry) $\exp_p$ from $T_pM$ to $M$ is well defined. Denote the norm on $T_pM$ induced by the Riemannian metric of $M$ by $\|\cdot\|_p$. Then $$K:=\{v\in T_pM:\|v\|_p\le \sqrt{c}\}$$ 
is a compact subset of $T_pM$, and hence $\exp_p(K)$ is a compact subset of $M$. By the definition of $\rho$, $S$ is a closed subset of $\exp_p(K)$, so $S$ is compact.

Comment: This argument does not work if $\sqrt c$ is greater than the injectivity radius at $p$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple application of the [Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf-Rinow_theorem): if $M$ is complete, then every closed and bounded subset is compact; since $\{x \in M : \rho(x,p) \le \sqrt c \}$ is clearly closed and bounded, it is compact.